# Opencv PCA Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location

Tags: c++, opencv, pca

I have a strange problem. I'm training a pca with a vector of data (Mat myData) as such:

```
PCA pca(myData, Mat(), CV_PCA_DATA_AS_ROW, 90);
```

The number of rows in myData coresponds to the number of samples. The strange thing is that if I train the PCA on about 90 samples it runs no problem but when I increase the number of sample it gives me the error:

> Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location

When I run the same code on Linux machine it also runs without any problems.

Does anyone have an idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason is that the input doesn't contain as much data as you'd think it does. As a result, OpenCV will perform an out-of-bound memory access.

This is Undefined Behavior, and is very likely to have different results on different systems. Simply using one element too much often is undetected by the OS, and your PCA won't be excessively wrong because of it.

Comment: Thanks. That was my first guess but i checked it and I still don't see where the problem is. There are 100 samples/rows passed to the PCA and during training it still gives me that error.